# Why won't SSH2 connect?

Tags: php, ssh, net-ssh, ssh2

First of all please accept my apologies for my lack of understanding of the basics here.  I am stuck with a problem and out of my depth.

We had a PHP script that was written by a long-gone member of staff. All it did was use ftp_ssl_connect() to connect to an FTP server and collect some files each evening.  The problem is that the vendor who supplies the files has changed to an SFTP server and I need to amend our script.

We are using a hopelessly out of date version of PHP: 5.6.40-0+deb8u5.  I can't change this, I'm afraid, not do I have access to install any libraries.  On the other hand, phpinfo() shows that libSSH Version: libssh2/1.4.3 is installed.  I also have access to webspace on Ionos which runs PHP version 8 and shows libSSH Version: libssh2/1.9.0 as being installed.

So my question is, why can't I get code like this to run?

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, $port);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) {
    echo "connection is authenticated";
} else {
    echo "failed!";
}
```

It is as if ssh2_connect() just isn't recognized but the library is installed, isn't it?

I have also seen that I might be able to use [Net_SSH](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_ssh_ssh2) but I have no idea where I am supposed to find the Included file from.

As I said, I'm really out of my depth so any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you determine that the library is installed? Is it loaded? Can it be loaded? Does that particular version even have such a function? BTW: "it is as if ..." -- thanks for your interpretation, but what are the actual observations? Please provide a [mcve], along with the output it produces. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, running old and obsolete software is often irresponsible, push for an update!